# AVERAGE using multiple criteria from multiple columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

I need to calculate the average value of a column contain temperature values (column H). The difficult part is that I want to average only specific cells of this column, that meet certain criteria. More specifically, I want to average temperature values from column H, only if the wind direction is northwest,which is detoned as "NW", the values of which are in column J, as well as if the wind speed is lower than 2 (column D). I used the AVERAGEIFS command but I recieve a message that "excel the formula you typed contains an error".

```
AVERAGEIFS($J$3:$J$5434;"NW";$H$3:$H$5434;D3:D5434;"<2")
```

Is the averageifs not the proper command to calculate this? Do you have any other ideas on how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H5434;J3:J5434;"NW";D3:D5434;"<2")
```

should work, where the main difference is that the column to be averaged comes first. Since there seems no need to copy this formula around the `$`s seem redundant.